# How do I get Materialize cards on the same row?

Tags: html, css

I am making a web page which is supposed to list cards on the same row, but instead my code is listing them one on top of each other as a column.

```css
.card-content{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="index-banner color2">
    <div class="section">

    <!--this is a card, starter hacks card-->
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col s3 m2">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.mlh.io/events/splashes/000/000/623/thumb/starterhacks_splash.png?1486582691>
          <a href="starterhacks.html" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Info</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h5>StarterHacks</h5>
          <h6>March 11th - 12th</h6>
          <h6>Waterloo, ON</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.mlh.io/events/splashes/000/000/622/thumb/ruhacks_splash.png?1486573836>
      <a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Info</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h5>RU Hacks</h5>
      <h6>March 17th - 8th</h6>
      <h6>Toronto, ON</h6>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

How would I format the cards to be listed one after another? I'm  new to HTML so I apologize if the answer is something blatantly obvious.
Thanks!

Edit: the CSS I have for this is the following *(in snippet)*

Comment: There are multiple options here, but do you have any CSS for what you've tried already, that you could include?

Comment: Yes I do, I just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your `.card` elements are set to get their width from their content, and that width is too big for them to both fit on the same line. In addition, `display: block` elements, like your div, will not jump onto the same line as one another by default. By setting a width for the elements, and adding `float: left`, you can get cards to be horizontally aligned with each other.

```css
.card {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.card-content{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="index-banner color2">
    <div class="section">

    <!--this is a card, starter hacks card-->
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col s3 m2">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.mlh.io/events/splashes/000/000/623/thumb/starterhacks_splash.png?1486582691>
          <a href="starterhacks.html" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Info</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h5>StarterHacks</h5>
          <h6>March 11th - 12th</h6>
          <h6>Waterloo, ON</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.mlh.io/events/splashes/000/000/622/thumb/ruhacks_splash.png?1486573836>
      <a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Info</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h5>RU Hacks</h5>
      <h6>March 17th - 8th</h6>
      <h6>Toronto, ON</h6>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked great :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @AmirYalamov. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue.